# Why Blazor Wasm is not able to detect gRPC Web call response?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, grpc-c#

I'm working on a .NET Microservices application, using .NET Aspire as a local runner. I have a Blazor WebAssembly wapp (web application) that connects to my .NET gRPC services.

I didn't have this problem in the past, but now when a gRPC method throws an exception as an error (a `RpcException`), the Blazor wapp throws a call canceled exception instead of correctly reporting the error status. For example in this code in my Blazor app:

```cs
try
{
    await SmsService.ValidateVerificationCodeAsync(new()
    {
        Phone = _verificationModel.Phone,
        Code = _verificationModel.VerificationCode
    });
}
catch(RpcException exception)
{
    if(exception.StatusCode == StatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        // Handle it
    }

    if(exception.StatusCode == StatusCode.InvalidArgument)
    {
        // Handle it
    }

    throw;
}
```

When the server throws the exception with the status set to Not Found, instead of getting into the if and handling it, it throws this in the browser's console:

```
blazor.web.js:1  crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="No grpc-status found on response. If the gRPC call is cross domain then CORS must be correctly configured. Access-Control-Expose-Headers needs to include 'grpc-status' and 'grpc-message'.")
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="No grpc-status found on response. If the gRPC call is cross domain then CORS must be correctly configured. Access-Control-Expose-Headers needs to include 'grpc-status' and 'grpc-message'.")
   at Bargeh.Main.Wapp.Client.Components.Pages.Login.OnVerificationSubmit() in C:\Source\Bargeh\Source\Wapps\Bargeh.Main.Wapp.Client\Components\Pages\Login.razor:line 352
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

You might guess that the server is canceling the call, but when I took a look at the network tab in the browser, I saw that the call is working properly, returning the correct error as headers as below:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/grpc-web
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2024 06:12:45 GMT
Grpc-Message: Not Found
Grpc-Status: 5
Server: Kestrel
```

Also I'm using DI in Blazor wapp to provide clients:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ =>
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()))
    {
        BaseAddress = new("https://localhost:5244")
    };

    GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(httpClient.BaseAddress, new() { HttpClient = httpClient });

    return new SmsProto.SmsProtoClient(channel);
});
```

The error can't be because of the wrong CORS configuration, because the request is sent and the response is back. I guess that the problem is from the gRPC client that is not able to detect the status, or it's canceling the call itself.

Comment: _"The error can't be because of the wrong CORS configuration, because the request is sent and the response is back."_ - But `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` is missing. Remember that CORS is enforced by the browser, not the server.

Comment: So @ProgrammingLlama do you think that the issue is from CORS? I guessed that because the reuqest has reached the WASM (and also I've configured CORS in gRPC servers) it's working fine.

Comment: In the response headers you showed above, I didn't see anything for exposing the two headers you need, so I think it probably is related to CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by simply adding a new middleware in my gRPC service's `Program.cs`:

```cs
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.AccessControlAllowOrigin = "*";
    context.Response.Headers.AccessControlExposeHeaders = "*";
    return next.Invoke();
});
```

**Note**: Allowing all possible things using the `*` character may put your service at a security risk, so use it with prior research